# Entered wrong username at cups and now I can't manage printers

Tags: cups

I just installed cups. When the webinterface asked me for username and password, I gave my regular user and not the root password. Now I can't log in (forbidden). I tried to clear the browsing data without success. What should I do?

Comment: As you already suspected, the login is stored in the browser. Most browsers will forget about this when restarted.

Answer (score 4):

As chirlu commented, restarting the browser solved this.

Answer (score 2):

Reopening the admin page in private mode worked for me.

Comment: IMO, this is the best answer.  It is insanely simple, and is not prone to issues when a browser might restore state even when it is stopped and restarted.

Comment: yes, that is the ONLY answer that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can just delete the session cookie for cups.

Here's how to do this in Mozilla Firefox:

(I'm using Firefox in German, so your menu item names might differ)

1. Open Menu → Settings (or type `about:preferences` into the address
   bar)
   In English this may be "Tools" → "Options".
2. Select tab "Privacy"
3. Click "[delete] individual cookies"
   In English this may be "Show Cookies..."
4. Search for "localhost" (or whatever the URL is you're running the
   CUPS interface on), find the cookie called `org.cups.sid` or similar,
   and delete it.
5. Reload the CUPS interface webpage, you should now be logged out.

Comment: This answer would be more usable if you would provide some instructions (i.e., explicit steps) for how to do this.

Comment: Sorry. Done! Added instructions for Firefox.

Comment: Though it would seem the best solution, deleting the cookie doesn't seem to work on Firefox 52.9.0.  Restarting the browser (no need to delete the cookie) worked.